# How to get e-mail address of current Jenkins user to use in groovy script

Tags: email, groovy, jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I've created a groovy script for the new Jenkins Workflow Plugin, https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin. I want it to send a mail to the user who started the job when it needs input for the next step. I've tried to search the API but I can't find anything about getting the users email address.

I would think of something like this.

```
import hudson.model.User
def user = User.current()
def mailAddress = user.getMailAddress()
```

Is there a way to get the current Jenkins user' address in groovy?

Answer (score 25):

I found a way:

```
import hudson.model.AbstractProject
import hudson.tasks.Mailer
import hudson.model.User

def item = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem(env.JOB_NAME) 
def build = item.getLastBuild()
def cause = build.getCause(hudson.model.Cause.UserIdCause.class)
def id = cause.getUserId()
User u = User.get(id)
def umail = u.getProperty(Mailer.UserProperty.class)
print umail.getAddress()
```

Comment: As of 1.4 you should use `currentBuild.rawBuild` rather than looking up the job and asking for its `lastBuild`.

Answer (score 10):

You can access the object of the current user with the method `current()`

```
def user = hudson.model.User.current();
```

The email address can be retrieved in the same way as to what you have done in your answer.

```
print user.getProperty(hudson.tasks.Mailer.UserProperty.class).getAddress();
```

Comment: In a workflow plugin job `hudson.model.User.current();` returns the SYSTEM user. Not the user that started the build. In our setup SYSTEM does not have a mail address so this returns null.

Comment: Yep. I'm glad this is settled :)

Comment: Still upvoting as I needed exactly this one - for setting default values for parametrized builds.

Comment: Thanks a ton. You saved me hours of research.

Answer (score 3):

```
import hudson.tasks.Mailer;
import hudson.model.User;
import hudson.model.Cause;
import hudson.model.Cause.UserIdCause;

def cause = build.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause)
def id = cause.getUserId()
User u = User.get(id)
def umail = u.getProperty(Mailer.UserProperty.class)
print umail.getAddress()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the `build` variable in the Java code of your plugin (for instance in the `setUp()` method of the class that extends `BuildWrapper`), you can get the currently logged user this way :

```
@Override
public MyJenkinsPlugin setUp(AbstractBuild build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener)

    String connectedUser = build.getCause(Cause.UserIdCause.class).getUserId();
    String mail = User.get(connectedUser.getProperty(hudson.tasks.Mailer.UserProperty.class).getEmailAddress()
...
}
```

I have not been able to get the logged user using `User.current().getId()`, it always returned me '`SYSTEM`'.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the author name and then use it for an example on a mailing registry or something like that:

```
 def author = ""
 def changeSet = currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets               
 for (int i = 0; i < changeSet.size(); i++) 
    {
       def entries = changeSet[i].items;
       for (int i = 0; i < changeSet.size(); i++) 
                {
                           def entries = changeSet[i].items;
                           def entry = entries[0]
                           author += "${entry.author}"
                } 
     }
     print author;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following routine:

```
import hudson.tasks.Mailer;
import hudson.model.User;

/**@
* Get user's email
*
* @param id null for a user who triggered the current build or name otherwise
* @return user's email
*/

def getUserEmail(String id=null) {
    User user = User.getById(id ?: currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(Cause.UserIdCause).getUserId(), false)
    user?.getProperty(Mailer.UserProperty.class).getAddress()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My script is as below:

```
import jakarta.mail.Message

def cause = build.getCause(hudson.model.Cause.UserIdCause.class)
def id = cause.getUserId()
def user = hudson.model.User.get(id)
def email = user.getProperty(hudson.tasks.Mailer.UserProperty.class).getAddress()

msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, email)
```