# Jenkins Pipeline currentBuild.changeSets and retrieving emails per repository

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline job, that check outs three repositories.

When the build fails, depending on where it fails, I want to send emails to the developers which caused the last commits/changes.

I can retrieve the authors full names with this:

```java
def changeSet = script.currentBuild.changeSets[0];
Set authors = [];
if (changeSet != null) {
    for (change in changeSet.items) {
        authors.add(change.author.fullName)
    }
}
```

But I cannot figure out:

1. How can I get the authors email?
2. How can I distinguish the authors for different repositories?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the author name and then use it for an example on a mailing registry or something like that:

```
def author = ""
def changeSet = currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets               
for (int i = 0; i < changeSet.size(); i++) 
{
   def entries = changeSet[i].items;
   for (int i = 0; i < changeSet.size(); i++) 
            {
                       def entries = changeSet[i].items;
                       def entry = entries[0]
                       author += "${entry.author}"
            } 
 }
 print author;
```

Answer (score 7):

See more here: 
[How to get e-mail address of current Jenkins user to use in groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046312/how-to-get-e-mail-address-of-current-jenkins-user-to-use-in-groovy-script)

```
echo 'author email:' + change.author.getProperty(hudson.tasks.Mailer.UserProperty.class).getAddress()
```

But it required disable groovy sandbox :(

Possibly solution has been add this to **Jenkins Pipeline Shared Libraries**: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Like this:

```
$ cat GetUserEmail.groovy 
#!/usr/bin/groovy

def call(body) {
    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config
    body()

    def User = config.get('user')
    return User.getProperty(hudson.tasks.Mailer.UserProperty.class).getAddress()
}
```

And use like this:

```
def changeSet = script.currentBuild.changeSets[0];
Set authors = [];
if (changeSet != null) {
    for (change in changeSet.items) {
        authors.add(GetUserEmail{user=change.author})
    }
}
```

Comment: Great.  Also, a shared library is also excellent.  It can push more code into something which can be more easily tested.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved directly with [Email Extension Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) that is used for sending emails.

1.Install the plugin

2.Use below code snippet in the post stage of

Scripted Pipeline:

```
 emailext (

  subject: "FAILED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'",
  body: """<p>FAILED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]':</p>
  <p>Check console output at "<a href="${env.BUILD_URL}">${env.JOB_NAME}[${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a>"</p>""",
  recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
)
```

Here `DevelopersRecipientProvider` contains all the change/commit owners(developers) emails

Declarative Pipeline:

```
 emailext body: "<p>Build Status: ${currentBuild.currentResult}<br><br> Check logs at <a href='${env.BUILD_URL}console'> Build Console Logs </a></p>",
            mimeType: 'text/html',
            subject: "[${currentBuild.currentResult}] Jenkins Job: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
            to:'xxx@xxx.com',
            recipientProviders: [developers()],
            from:'xxx@xxx.com'
```

Here `developers()` contains all the change/commit owners(developers) emails