# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: script for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to get email address of the committer with Jenkinsfile (groovy script)

I used this solution approved here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46648279/10899655

My code:

```
@Library('shared-libraries') _ 
pipeline{
  //my stages here

}
post { 
    always { 
        script { 
            def changeSet = script.currentBuild.changeSets[0]; 
            Set authors = []; 
            if (changeSet != null) { 
                for (change in changeSet.items) { 
                    authors.add(GetUserEmail{user=change.author}) 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

However I get this error message :

```
Error when executing always post condition:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: script for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

How can I fix that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please provide your pipeline code?

Comment: Can you add your source to the original post with formatting?  It is hard to understand as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no `script` variable defined in the line

```
def changeSet = script.currentBuild.changeSets[0];
```

You need to define it first.